# How to stub a function IN a Helper during test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Take a look at this helper function:

```
def show_welcome_banner?
  (controller_name == 'competition' && action_name == 'index') ||
  (controller_name == 'submissions' && action_name == 'show')
end
```

It expects the controller_name and action_name functions to be defined.

I tried to use this in my RSpec matcher:

```
describe PageHelper do
  it "should know when the welcome banner is to be shown" do
    helper.stub!(:controller_name).and_return('index')
    show_welcome_banner?.should == false
  end
end
```

But this won't really work.

How could I stub the functions INSIDE the helper? Perhaps using instance_eval? 
Thanks!

**EDIT**,
tried to use

```
controller.stub!(:controller_name).and_return('index')
```

but got

```
  1) PageHelper should know when the welcome banner is to be shown
     Failure/Error: show_welcome_banner?.should == false
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `controller_name' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x1059a10b8>
     # ./app/helpers/page_helper.rb:16:in `show_welcome_banner?'
     # ./spec/helpers/page_helper_spec.rb:7
```

The helper is put in **spec/helper/page_helper_spec.rb**..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
stub!(:controller_name).and_return('index')
```

Seems to have worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this in your Rspec?

```
controller.stub!(:controller_name).and_return('index')
```

The helpers are just modules that get included in `ApplicationController`. I believe that method comes from `ActionController::Base`.

Comment: Try `@controller` instead of `controller`.

Answer (score 0):

rspec-rails 3.5

```
allow(helper).to receive(:controller_name) { 'submissions' }
```