# How can I stub a function call with rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

The code I'm working on looks like:

```
class A
  def get_news

    when self.type = 'TypeA'
        param1 = 'a'
        param2 = 'b'
    else
        param1 = 'c'
        param2 = 'd'
    end

    @news ||= B.new.get_news(param1, param2)
  end
end
```

I would like to be able to test that the right parameters get passed to `B#get_news`. 
Do you know a way to stub the function call, so I can test that it gets called with the correct parameters instead of testing that a request gets made with the correct parameters?

I have spent some time on it and I can't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Did you try **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927132/how-to-stub-a-function-in-a-helper-during-test)**?

Comment: @kgdesouz - that won't work for stubbing instances that are created only after calling the method under test

Comment: To the OP: calling `self.type = 'TypeA'` doesn't compare the 2 values - it assigns it.  Use `==` instead

Answer (score 0):

First stub out `any_instance` of B:

```
B.any_instance.stubs(:get_news)
```

Then have the spec call your method.  You can then verify that `get_news` was called using `expect_any_instance_of`:

```
expect_any_instance_of(B).to receive(:get_news).with(..., ...)
```

Pass whatever values to `with()` you are expecting the `get_news` method to come along with.